# Fragment Navigation with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer, fragment-backstack

i actually have a little Problem with my Android App.

My App Contains a Navigation Drawer which is used to navigate inside the App.
For Example

Navigation Drawer:

1. Overview
2. Search
3. Users
4. Stuff

When the App starts, i will load the Overview fragment.
If the user clicks the other Items, i'll change the fragments with:

```
final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

The problem was now, when the user switched, for example, from 1 > 2 > 4 > 3 and them pressing the back key, it will bring him just one fragment back. 3 > 4 > 2 > 1

So i added the code, which will bring him back to Fragment 1 on each Backpress.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    int exit = 0;


    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = new Overview();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack("fragBack").commit();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ok, first it was fine, but now i added some more fragments on a Deeper Level, but they should't go back to Fragment 1 on back press.

For Example

1. Overview (the Main Fragment)
2. Search (Back Key goes Back to Fragment 1)
3. Users (Back Key goes Back to Fragment 1)
4. Stuff (Back Key goes Back to Fragment 1)

4.1 Details (Back Key goes Back to Fragment 4. Stuff) < 4.1.1 More Details (Back Key goes Back to Fragment 4.1)

Would be nice if somebody has a Idea how i could handle the Navigation in my app.

Greetz

Comment: Is there a specific reason to make the back button behave like this? Normally users would expect the back button to take them to the previous screen, not a main screen.

Comment: `transaction.replace` is going to remove your current fragment and add in the new one. You should use `transaction.add` when going to a deeper level of fragment so that it is added to the backstack.

Comment: Yeah so mainactivity from the App is the Overview and if you go from the Overview to the Settings and then to the Search you dont want to go back to the Settings,if you press back

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and need to change the logic. 
Whenever you go from the navigationdrawer, first you clear all the fragments in the stack using this code

```
private void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
```

and second, add the corresponding selected(1 or 2 or 3) fragment to the stack.

```
private void navigateToFragment(Fragment fragment, String TAG){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, TAG);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

And when you go deeper like 2 -> 2.1 -> 2.2, on backpress you will return 2.2 ->2.1 ->2.
No need to override the onKeyDown() method and add fragments again

Comment: The Idea is good, but when i clear the BackStack before navigating to a other Fragment, i cant go back to the Overview Fragment, if the Backkey is pressed

Comment: ok...then override the onBackPressed() method and check the backstackentry count and if it is 0 then call your OverviewFragment